# How to get the value of the root?

Tags: approximation

I have this statement:

> If $\frac{\sqrt{7}}{\sqrt{5}+\sqrt{3}} \approx \frac{2}{3}$, Which of
>   the following values are the closest to $\sqrt{21}$ ?
>
> A) 68/15 B) 14/3 C) 19/4 D) 55/12 E) 9/2

My development was:

$\frac{\sqrt{7}}{\sqrt{5}+\sqrt{3}}  = \frac{\sqrt{35}-\sqrt{21}}{2} \approx \frac{2}{3}$

My idea was to treat the sign $\approx$ as a sign $=$ and thus eliminate roots and clear $\sqrt21$, with which I have obtained $55/12$ but I do not know if this is correct.

$\frac{\sqrt{35}-\sqrt{21}}{2} = \frac{2}{3}$

$35 = (\frac{4}{3} +\sqrt{21})^2$

$\sqrt{21} = \frac{110}{9} * \frac{3}{8} = 55/12$

So my doubt is: Can I treat a $\approx$ sign as a $=$ sign to work like an normal equation?

Comment: Can you tell how did you get the value as $\frac{55}{12}$? I can't see it even by treating $\approx$ as $=$?

Comment: @Rick I already edited it

Answer (score 1):

Rearrange:
$$\frac{\sqrt{7}}{\sqrt{5}+\sqrt{3}} \approx \frac{2}{3} \iff \frac{7}{\sqrt{35}+\sqrt{21}} \approx \frac{2}{3} \Rightarrow \sqrt{21}\approx \frac{21}{2}-\sqrt{35}$$
Use linear approximation to find $f(35)=\sqrt{35}$:
$$f(x_0+\Delta x)\approx f(x_0)+f'(x_0)\cdot \Delta x \ ;\\
f(36-1)\approx f(36)+\frac1{2\sqrt{36}}\cdot (-1)=6-\frac1{12}=\frac{71}{12}$$
So:
$$\frac{21}{2}-\frac{71}{12}=\frac{126-71}{12}=\frac{55}{12}.$$

Comment: IMHO an unpleasant solution.  Approximating in $(81/4,9/2)$ gives immediately $\sqrt{21}\approx\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\frac{81}{4}}}(21-81/4)+9/2=55/12$.

Comment: Nice! Next approximation point is $(324/16,18/4)$. But this method is not referring to the given condition or the OP’s $\sqrt{35}$.

Comment: I don't need a solution, i need a answer to my doubt. And a solution with properties of roots and elemental algebra

Answer (score 1):

From
$$\left(\frac23\right)^2\approx\left(\frac{\sqrt7}{\sqrt5+\sqrt3}\right)^2$$
we get
$$\frac49\approx\frac{7}{5+3+2\sqrt{15}},$$
hence $\sqrt{15}\approx31/8$.
 Now we have
$$\frac{2\sqrt{3}}3\approx
\frac{\sqrt7\sqrt3}{\sqrt5+\sqrt3}=\frac{\sqrt{21}}{\sqrt5+\sqrt3}.$$
Using the approximate value for $\sqrt{15}$ we arrive in
$$\sqrt{21}\approx\frac{55}{12}.$$

Comment: Can you explain how you get $\sqrt{15} \approx 31/8$, please.

Comment: See my edit, please.

Comment: +1. Elegant and expected answer.